# My app works fine on emulator, but crashes on device?

Tags: java, android, android-applicationinfo

**My Device Api level is 18**

The app builds with no errors in it and it runs fine on emulator, but when i build an apk or if i directly run the app in device using usb debugging mode,the app gets installed and when i open it, it shows "App Unfortunately stopped" even in bluestacks i encounter same problem. Please help me with it

> Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haptechinnovations.caffeine.caffeinecoders">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"
              android:targetSdkVersion="26"
              android:maxSdkVersion="27"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".youtube" />
        <activity android:name=".facebook"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Build Gradle (Module: app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.haptechinnovations.caffeine.caffeinecoders"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**Stack Trace**

> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.haptechinnovations.caffeine.caffeinecoders.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.haptechinnovations.caffeine.caffeinecoders.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0x7f07007d
>                                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:460)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:117)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:250)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:172)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:98)
>
> Main Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private WebView mywebView;
String url = "https://www.youtube.com/caffeinecoders";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://caffeincoder.wordpress.com/");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_open) {
            boolean isAppExists;
            isAppExists = isInstalled ("com.google.android.youtube");
            if(isAppExists==true) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "YouTube App Not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

private boolean isInstalled(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean isIn;
    try{
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri,PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        isIn=true;
    }catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        isIn=false;
    }
    return isIn;
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_youtube) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,youtube.class);
        startActivity(intent);


        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,facebook.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: Stack trace updated.

Comment: why do you have this line in manifest?  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"
              android:targetSdkVersion="26"
              android:maxSdkVersion="27"/>`

Comment: I just saw that in android developer site. I just gave a try by giving these to  my device api levels.I removed those and tried too..but no use

Comment: Ok, can you post your `MainActivity` xml

Comment: android is not able to inflate your main activity xml file properly. Something related to `NavigationView` is broken

Comment: And your main activity code please

Comment: can you check your `nav_header_main.xml` and `activity_main_drawer.xml` layout  files for drawable invalid/nonExistent references

Comment: Main activity code added. NavigationView erro? what exactly gone wrong ??

Comment: And another thing is, it worked fine on device with android lollipop 5.1! is there any problem with API levels?

Comment: No, API levels looks ok. What have you defined in build.gradle for min SDK, compile SDK and target SDK

Answer (score 1):

May Be A UI issue. As an example you have Designed your App for Mobile and tablet. If you have missed some codes in mobile Ui(XML file) it wont run in mobile. But it will work fine in Tablet. Please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007d

This is your problem. 
open your R file to see which resource is creating the problem.

Another time the issue occurs is if you are trying to call set text while parsing an int which makes android look for a resource that maps to the integer value instead.

Posting code of the activity where the crash occurs might help

Comment: The resource with that resource id is not present